# How does diluting acetic acid affect its reaction with sodium bicarbonate?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

I am writing a lab on an experiment where I gradually diluted vinegar and reacted it with baking soda. I am aware that diluting vinegar makes the it weak, and therefore, lessens the amount of gas produced. For my lab, I need sources to support my idea that diluting the vinegar lessens the amount of gas produced when reacted with baking soda. Even a source or evidence that diluting any other liquid and reacting it with a solid would be useful. I do not know where to find information like this.

Answer (score 1):

Have you actually done the experiment yet? The most convincing support you can have for your conjecture is your experimental results.

Once you have the results, then you try to explain them on the basis of established chemical principles. One of those principles is stoichiometry: acetic acid and sodium bicarbonate always react in a fixed proportion-1:1 mole ratio. Another is that carbon dioxide has limited solubility in water -- less water present means less carbon dioxide will remain dissolved.

If you cannot explain the phenomenon based on established chemical principles, that is where the fun begins!